# Not able to install youtube-dl

Tags: linux, debian, youtube-dl

I have tried almost everything I could find on google but could not install `youtube-dl` on Debian Mint.

**Try 1**

Installed and updated with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl 

sudo youtube-dl -U
```

But when tried

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwYatpwrs8s
```

Then I got

> Hi! We changed distribution method and now youtube-dl needs to update itself one more time.
>       This will only happen once. Simply press enter to go on. Sorry for the trouble!
>       From now on, get the binaries from http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html, not from the git repository.

Then I went to `http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html` and followed the installation instructions:

**Try 2**

```
sudo wget http://youtube-dl.org/downloads/2013.05.23/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Got the same error about the distribution change and new link.

**Try 3**

So I installed pip on my debian first and ran

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

But I am still getting same error and I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: youtube-dl does not need to be installed, just download it, assign exec permission and use it as usual, ./youtube-dl path-to-video

Comment: @sgmart Are you sure about it. Are you talking about _Youtube-dl.tar.gz_

Comment: Yep, I'm sure, here's the link: https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html. Since it's a python module, it also can be installed using `pip` as showed in the previous link. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Just re-execute `sudo youtube-dl -U` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to update to the latest version. With your second try, you installed it a second time (to `/usr/local/bin/` instead of `/usr/bin`) - you want only one.

Alternatively, simply uninstall youtube-dl with `sudo apt-get remove -y youtube-dl`. That should make the local version (`/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`) the first one in your PATH again - if your PATH contains `/usr/local/bin`. If it doesn't, you can also just install youtube-dl to `/usr/bin`, with the following commands:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already install remove it:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/youtube-dl
sudo apt-get remove -y youtube-dl
```

Try the following command

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
hash -r
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with this:
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/3908

Use the following commands to update:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/youtube-dl  # or apt-get remove -y youtube-dl
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```